# What ports does Alien Swarm use?

Tags: networking, alien-swarm

I keep on getting disconnected from Alien Swarm (after 10 retries the game auto disconnects) and I remembered that I have very few ports forwarded to my computer.

What ports should I forward to my computer so that I can play most effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `27015` is the port you should be forwarding for client connection. A server can be hosted on any port, but this appears to be the default one.

If you want to host a dedicated server, you would need to forward `27005` as well.

Alternatively, [this post on Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1369712) suggests enabling

> - UDP 27000 to 27020 inclusive
> - TCP 27020 to 27050 inclusive

Comment: So, I think those are the right ports, but I can't tell, because I'm having connection difficulties still. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen [a post on Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1379419) which says that you need ports 27005, 27015, 27020, and 49872. When you forward the ports in range 27000-27050, this covers the first three of this list, but not the last one.